# Linq select specific record cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using ASP.NET 3.5 with C#.

I have taken `string` variables like :

```
string Re = string.Empty; 
string In = string.Empty; 
string deWithT = string.Empty; 
string deWithoutTt = string.Empty; 
string ki = string.Empty;
```

I have a `DataSet` in which `Tables[0]` contains following table data.

```
Id  Name    Param           Value

87  E       Re              AT
88  E       In              00
89  E       deWithT         VK
90  E       deWithoutTt     CK
91  E       ki              VH
```

Now If I want to get the `value` of specific `param` in `variable`, I need to go for `foreach` or `for loop`. But I don't want to do that. I want to `fetch value of each param into respective variable` using `linq`. Any one help? Sorry, I am new to using `linq` so I don't have much knowledge how to perform such thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Param` is unique, you can use `ToDictionary` to convert to Dictionary for better performance O(1):

```
var dic = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(r => r.Field<string>("Param"), 
                          r => r.Field<string>("Value"));
```

Then you can get the value:

```
Re = dic["Re"];
....
```

Comment: DataTable has not a ToDictionary method. You need it as enumerable at first.

Answer (score 2):

`Dictionar<string,string>` would be a better option here, where `Key` can be `Param` and `Value` can be `Value` from the DataTable.

You can do:

```
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = 
                  dt.AsEnumerable()
                  .ToDictionary(r=> r.Field<string>("Param"), r=> r.Field<string>("Value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for Param/values:

```
datatable.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary(d=>d.Field<string>("Param"),
                                            v=>v.Field<string>("Value"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you may want to revise your query of datatable in order to get the specific row with the param like

declare your param var

```
string str_param="Re";
```

then update your datatable query to something like this

```
DataTable dt1 = GetDataTable("select * from table where param=str_param", null);
```

then you can store the result in string

```
string Re = dt1.Rows[0]["Param"].ToString();
```